# Switching between pages on selecting the radio button without redirect or submit

Tags: javascript, php

i am a bee on PHP and i want a solution to switch between two pages on when selecting a radio button with out submit the page  or redirecting the page ?

Which one is the more appropriate way

1. javascript or
2. php ?

Please help me with a suitable example.Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "switching between two pages without submit or redirect"?  If you don't want the page context to change at all then how are you "switching" pages?  If you're not posting to the server and doing this all client-side then clearly this would be done with JavaScript.  PHP would be involved if anything is needed server-side.

Comment: You can do this with Javascript but you have to load the two pages in different containers and using radio buttons you can switch the visibility of the two containers.

Answer (score 0):

**Trythis:**

you can simple call a link , if you don't have a container in that page to load the new page when radio button is pressed .

You have no option that link the radio with page link ,

But , if you want to load the content of that page inside you php page without redirecting ot post then ur ultimate friend is JQuery and Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with Jquery / Javascript in better way:

Try this:

```js
$("#example").change(function(){
window.location="http://www.example.com/";
});

$("#wiki").change(function(){
window.location="http://www.wikipedia.org/";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="example"> Example Side <br/>
<input type="radio" id="wiki"> Wikipedia Side
```

Comment: This can be done using javascript only. We don't need to use jQuery for this purpose only.